# Getting the environment variables for the current process on Linux

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables, porting

I am trying to port an application from Windows to Linux. In Windows I have a
GetEnvironmentStrings() function in windows.h which provides me the environment variables and their values in the current process in 
the form NAME=VALUE.

Is there an equivalent Linux function call for this? I need a C function.
How can this be achieved on Linux?

Comment: What language is this for? `env` is one linux command that will display the current environment

Comment: i know that set can also be used to display all env variables. But I need a C function for this.

Comment: There's a [`getenv`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html) command in stdlib.h. You can also access the environment variable `environ` directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the environment variables through the variable `extern char **environ;`.

[Read more](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html):

> The value of an environment variable is a string of characters. For a C-language program, an array of strings called the environment shall be made available when a process begins. The array is pointed to by the external variable environ, which is defined as:
>
> ```
> extern char **environ;
> ```
>
> These strings have the form `name=value`.

Answer (score 0):

There is [getenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv)()
Conforming to SVr4, POSIX.1-2001, 4.3BSD, C89, C99.